# A mean value theorem involving two functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f,g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$. Prove that there is a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that:
>   $$[f(b)-f(a)]g'(c) = [g(b)-g(a)]f'(c).$$

I think this is a straightforward application of the mean value theorem to a clever function. Am I right? If so, which function? Thanks :)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate question...the previous question was titled Generalized Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. Just consider the function $$h(x)=[f(b)-f(a)]g(x)-[g(b)-g(a)]f(x)$$ and apply Rolle's theorem to $h$ on the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: This is called [Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem).

Comment: may you seek for values of $c$ when $f'(c), g'(c) \neq 0 $

Comment: This is Cauchy's mean value theorem as @vadim123 said, and is crucial for proving L'Hopital's rule - although few calculus students seem to know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$
h(x)=(f(x)-f(a))(g(b)-g(a))-(f(b)-f(a))(g(x)-g(a))
$$
Then $h(a)=h(b)=0$. By Rolle's Theorem, there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that
$$
h'(c)=f'(c)(g(b)-g(a))-(f(b)-f(a))g'(c)=0
$$
Or
$$f'(c)(g(b)-g(a))=(f(b)-f(a))g'(c)$$